Help is needed with IC identification
I have a gateway laptop model P5SW0 which I got in none working condition. Taking measurement, some capacitor was identified to be shorted. Upon removal of the capacitor the short disappear, and further measurements revealed a chip (PU6) with a hole in it. It appears to be a DC-DC converter, as there is a coil with capacitors located next to it. The chip has a QFN package with dimensions of 3x3mm and 10 pins.
Due the hole on the chip I can not figure out it's correct marking but perhaps it could be BR-1LR/BA-1LR. A quick search in Google did not bring anything of this kind of chip.
From your experience does anything come to mind regarding this chip?
The mainboard is marked as "P5WE0 LA-6901P Rev: 2.0, 2011-05-23 Made in China".
Thank you for your assistance in identifying the chip.
Polar Bear





I think it's a DFN and not a QFN, if you say there's only 10 pins and I see 5 on one side.

@pipe - I have added a picture where all pins are visible. The package has two raws of contacts DFN (dual-flat no-leads), not QFN (quad-flat no-leads).

Could be "BA" as the prefix - which would point to a Rohm Semiconductor part, but this is just a guess

"BP" rather than "BR" based on the part found in the answer.

This is of course very fascinating, but did you think about the reason the converter has died? I would bet that the main CPU is dead, so why would you believe the board is worth to repair, especially if it is 13 years old??

I found the schematics here by searching for your P5WE0 Schematic, landing here, then checking Rev 2.0. Then I Ctrl+F searched the PDF for PU6 since that appears to be the part designator labeled on the board. That gets some good hits:

A block labeled RT8209BGQW
A block labeled SY8033BDBC (this is probably it since it - says DFN10)
The following schematic


Googling for SY8033BDBC turns up a component made by Silergy available from LCSC Electronics (a popular distributor in China). It doesn't seem like it's readily available in any mainstream distribution, but I did see someone on e-Bay selling them. Seems like you might be able to get them through Aliexpress as well.

Pictures of the SY8033 part show markings of "BP1xx", so seems to fit.
